# Getting error : 30034 US A2P 10DLC - Message from an Unregistered Number

Tags: twilio

I'm using Programmable messaging and am testing out the Live system. I sent out an SMS to 3 users but only 1 got it. For the other two, I checked in the console and it shows as undelivered with the following error;

> 30034 US A2P 10DLC - Message from an Unregistered Number

This is even though my number is registered on A2P 10DLC.

Any suggestions on what could be the issue here?

I have completed the A2P 10DLC registration a few weeks back and even received an email from Twilio verifying that the number has been registered, but when I generate the compliance report to check registration it shows the number as UNREGISTERED.